# VBA Excel - I need to replace this= ,""F with this= ,"F but not where it is this= ,"",

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry the title seems confusing. There is a workbook with large amounts of data that I am trying to write a Macro for. It is like Find/Replace but is very specific to the data that I have.

For example:
Replace:
,""Micky Mouse, Inc."","Donald Duck","",

With:
,"Micky Mouse, Inc.","Donald Duck","",

I need the last ,"", to be left alone. I'm not sure how to write this exactly.

I would prefer not to program for each example as these proper names are continuing to be added and would prefer not to have to re-write the VBA code each time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First replace `","",` with say `BROCKHAGER_KEY` and then replace all `""` with `"`. and then replace `BROCKHAGER_KEY` with `","",` :)

Answer (score 1):

You could always do an initial replace of the empty quotes and then do your normal replace. This is the most straightforward method.

```
Sub custFindReplace(srchRng As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In srchRng.Cells
        c.Value = Replace(c.Value, ","""",", ","""""""",")
        c.Value = Replace(c.Value, """""", """")
    Next c
End Sub
```

If your logic remains this simple, the more efficient method (as Siddarth suggested) should be to use the built-in find/replace:

```
Sub custFindReplace(srchRng As Range)
    srchRng.Replace What:=","""",", Replacement:=","""""""",", LookAt:=xlPart
    srchRng.Replace What:="""""", Replacement:="""", LookAt:=xlPart
End Sub
```

Comment: Looping is very slow as compared to `Cells.Replace` :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout True. Just depends on whether his logic gets more complicated.

Comment: + 1 Oops sorry, I didn't see that you edited your post.

Comment: @SiddharthRout That's fine. I think I only saved that edit about 10 seconds before your answer came through. My original code on my machine used a unique key (I think it was <BRQTP> or something) but I eliminated that because I figured *in this case* it was easier to just combine the second and third replacements.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment,

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim UniqueKey As String

    UniqueKey = "BROCKHAGER_KEY"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells
        .Replace What:=""",""""", Replacement:=UniqueKey, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        .Replace What:="""""", Replacement:="""", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        .Replace What:=UniqueKey, Replacement:=""",""""", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that this might actually work. I will do some testing on the data to be sure. Also I wanted to add a MsgBox that says "You have replaced n errors" on the screen so I can talk with the users about how many of these were replaced. I tried putting in "Count = Count + 1" but obviously it has to be written differently. Thanks for this and I will let you know how testing goes on this.

Comment: If you want the count then you will have to do the replacing in a loop using `.FindNext`. See [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: OK. I did testing. There are 2 errors:  **260857761,","Roger McCullough","64800262",** is supposed to be **260857761,"","Roger McCullough","64800262",** where it leaves the double quotes in.

Comment: AND **203980919,"00000000",""Frank W. Berlin & Associates L.L.C.","656",** is supposed to be **203980919,"00000000","Frank W. Berlin & Associates L.L.C.","656",** where it takes the "" out

Comment: When trying Mark's it says "argument not optional"

Comment: @BrockHager Did you pass a range object (srchRng) to that method?? By that error message, I would guess not.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I am supposed to do that. I am new to VBA

Comment: I added this 'Sub InsertTest()
    remove_errors ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
    
    
End Sub'

Comment: After adding that new SUB then I ran it and expected to replace around 1,000. It instead replaced over 1,064,000. It is finding way too many to replace.